# RelativeLayout programmatically margins not working

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, padding, margins

```
    LinearLayout usersPlaceholder = Main.lay_found_users;   //Found Users Placeholder

    //RelativeLayout Params
    RelativeLayout userlay = new RelativeLayout(mCtx);      //Create new Element
    userlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_useritem); //Background
    userlay.setGravity(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);   //Gravity
    userlay.setClickable(true);                             //Clickable

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dp(80));
    relativeParams.setMargins(dp(80), dp(80), dp(80), dp(80));
    userlay.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
    userlay.requestLayout();
    usersPlaceholder.addView(userlay);
```

Margins are not setting. The `RelativeLayout` which is the child element, is expanding until match the parent `usersPlaceholder` which is a `LinearLayout`. I also tried setting paddings to the parent element but the same problem...

This method transforms the measures

```
    public int dp(int dps){
    final float scale = mCtx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class Main extends Activity{

   Context ctx;
   public static LinearLayout lay_found_users;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.act_main);

      lay_found_users = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay_found_users);
   }
}
```

Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Dont call requestLayout() the system will call for you

Comment: Okay thanks, I called it because I read it could be a solution, but both calling or not calling don't make margins work :/

Comment: Share more the code. this code is pretty straight forward and i dont the issue is here. Main.lay_found_useres. share this view

Comment: Main is the main `Activity` and lay_found_users is just the parent `LinearLayout` declared static. Sharing more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`and `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` extends `MarginLayoutParams`, which explains why some settings apply for both Layouts. If you set a parameter that is not available in the layout, it's simply ignored.

When using `RelativeLayout`, I would use `padding` instead of `margins`. It might solve your problem.

`Padding` is set directly on the view, and not on the `LayoutParams`. So for example: `userLay.setPadding(dp(80),dp(80),dp(80),dp(80));`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, but I don't understand it. I made the margins work, creating `LayoutParams` from `LinearLayout` this way:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dp(80));
```

I don't get it because I've created a new `RelativeLayout`:

```
RelativeLayout userlay = new RelativeLayout(mCtx);
```

I'm applying `LinearLayout` parameters to a `RelativeLayout`

Layout types don't match but params work. Can someone tell me why? Thanks.